# Cucumber/Capybara: Could not launch browser window

Tags: selenium, webdriver, cucumber, capybara, jruby

I am using Cucumber/Capybara framework using Jruby. I have setup all the things required to run the test.  When I execute it, no error message is displayed, but webdriver window also does not come up. I have tried with Mozilla Firefox 17.0.1 and 22.0 version. I am using a windows 7 machine. My other teammates have followed the same process, but they are able to run the tests.

```
C:\Application>bundle exec cucumber features\login.feature

Mocha deprecation warning: Change `require 'mocha'` to `require 'mocha/setup'`.

Rack::File headers parameter replaces cache_control after Rack 1.5.
Using the default profile...
Feature: Login
  In order to adhere to GIS requirements
  As an employee
  I want to be able to log in using the enterprise single sign on

  Scenario: Login to home page←[90m                            # features\login.feature:6←[0m
```

No Webdriver window getting launched.